# Python Selenium move_to_element method of ActionChains not working

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, action

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.wikipedia.org/')
time.sleep(2)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_by_offset(500, 500).perform()
```

`move_to_element()`, `move_to_element_by_offset()`

None of the function works.

No error is reported.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7890

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any such issues with your code trials. However it is to benoted that, **ActionChains** are a way to automate low level interactions such as mouse movements, mouse button actions, key press, and context menu interactions. This class is also useful for doing the complex actions like hover over and drag and drop. To simulate all these *low level interactions* and *complex actions* **ActionChains** Class is used rather than using the **Keyboard** or **Mouse** directly.

So, though the `move_by_offset()` method gets executed visibly you may not be able to trace/track it.